# Remove results below a certain score threshold in Solr/Lucene?

Tags: lucene, solr

Is there a built-in functionalities in solr/lucene to filter the results if they fall below a certain score threshold? Let's say if I provide a score threshold of .2, then all documents with score less than .2 will be removed from my results. My intuition is that this is possible by updating/customizing solr or lucene.

Could you point me to right direction on how to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Simon's answer is correct. But bear in mind that socres are relative and hence it's hard to pick a threshold for "goodness" of results.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could write your own Collector that would ignore collecting those documents that the scorer places below your threshold. Below is a simple example of this using Lucene.Net 2.9.1.2 and C#. You'll need to modify the example if you want to keep the calculated score.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Lucene.Net.Index;
using Lucene.Net.Search;

public class ScoreLimitingCollector : Collector {
    private readonly Single _lowerInclusiveScore;
    private readonly List<Int32> _docIds = new List<Int32>();
    private Scorer _scorer;
    private Int32 _docBase;

    public IEnumerable<Int32> DocumentIds {
        get { return _docIds; }
    }

    public ScoreLimitingCollector(Single lowerInclusiveScore) {
        _lowerInclusiveScore = lowerInclusiveScore;
    }

    public override void SetScorer(Scorer scorer) {
        _scorer = scorer;
    }

    public override void Collect(Int32 doc) {
        var score = _scorer.Score();
        if (_lowerInclusiveScore <= score)
            _docIds.Add(_docBase + doc);
    }

    public override void SetNextReader(IndexReader reader, Int32 docBase) {
        _docBase = docBase;
    }

    public override bool AcceptsDocsOutOfOrder() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Simon. This really gave me much better understanding on how to implement it. 

@Shashikant - thanks also for sharing your thoughts. I'll keep that in mind. I'll just be more cautious in setting the threshold so that  there'll be small chance that I filter out relevant results.

Answer (score 6):

It's called normalized score ([Scores As Percentages](http://wiki.apache.org/lucene-java/ScoresAsPercentages)).

You can use the following the following parameters to achieve that:

```
ns = {!func}product(scale(product(query({!type=edismax v=$q}),1),0,1),100)
fq = {!frange l=20}$ns
```

Where 20 is your 20% threshold.

Related: [how do I normalise a solr/lucene score?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3986220/how-do-i-normalise-a-solr-lucene-score/15765254#15765254)

---

> I would not recommend doing this because absolute score values in Lucene
>   are not meaningful (e.g., scores are not directly comparable across
>   searches).  The ratio of a score to the highest score returned is
>   meaningful, but there is no absolute calibration for the highest score
>   returned, at least at present, so there is not a way to determine from
>   the scores what the quality of the result set is overall.  There are
>   various approaches to improving this that have been discussed (making
>   the scores more directly comparable by encoding additional information
>   into the score and using that for normalization, or probably better,
>   generalizing the score to an object that contains multiple pieces of
>   information; e.g. the total number of query terms matched by the top
>   result if you are using default OR would be quite useful).  None of
>   these ideas are implemented yet as far as I know. - @Chuck

<sup>Source: [RE: Limiting Hits with a score threshold](http://web.archive.org/web/20090813104038/http://article.gmane.org:80/gmane.comp.jakarta.lucene.user/12076)</sup>

Related: [Re: A question about scoring function in Lucene](http://web.archive.org/web/20090323040248/http://article.gmane.org:80/gmane.comp.jakarta.lucene.user/10810)

Answer (score 0):

Just an update for anyone who stumbles here - an [EarlyTerminatingSortCollector](http://lucene.apache.org/core/6_4_1/core/org/apache/lucene/search/EarlyTerminatingSortingCollector.html) has been provided by Lucene and a custom collector does not need to be made for this anymore. Wrap it over [TopDocsCollector](https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_4_1/core/org/apache/lucene/search/TopDocsCollector.html) (in OP's specific case, [TopScoreDocCollector](https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_4_1/core/org/apache/lucene/search/TopScoreDocCollector.html)) to achieve the given task.

**EarlyTerminatingSortCollector**

> A Collector that early terminates collection of documents on a per-segment basis, if the segment was sorted according to the given Sort.

**TopDocsCollector**

> A base class for all collectors that return a TopDocs output. This collector allows easy extension by providing a single constructor which accepts a PriorityQueue as well as protected members for that priority queue and a counter of the number of total hits.