# Lucene: How to get the similarity between a query and a text

Tags: lucene, information-retrieval, similarity

I have a lot of queries for one text. Example "North America", "Europe", "Asia" (queries) and one text (e.g. a large text about the USA (e.g. the Wikipedia article)).

Now I build an index of the large text and after that I send the above mentioned queries. Now Lucene (version 4) calculates a score. But as I know through different searches, this is no real percentage and no real similarity between the query and the text.
With TFIDFSimilarity I only get very small scores (<0.05)

But I wish to get the following similarities:
"North America" ==> 90%
 "Europe", "Asia" ==> 40%

.. or something else, but it should be a real similarity.

What can I do? Does somebody have any ideas?

Comment: Lucene scoring is not intended to represent percentages, and can not be effectively normalized to them.  See [here](http://wiki.apache.org/lucene-java/ScoresAsPercentages) and [here](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.jakarta.lucene.user/12076).

Comment: possible duplicate of [how do I normalise a solr/lucene score?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3986220/how-do-i-normalise-a-solr-lucene-score)

Comment: I already read about not using the score as %. Now I ' m using the term frequency in order to get such results.