# How to get percentage matchingscore values in Lucene.Net 3.0

Tags: c#, lucene.net

I am upgrading our searchengine to Lucene.Net 3.0.3.0.
Also i am completely revising the searchengine for our websites, because there were some issues with scoring.
So I am building it from the ground up (again). The first thing that strikes me as weird is that the scoring values are incomprehensible. In the previous version of Lucene I was using it returned scores between 0 and 1, which are easily translated to a percentage.
After upgrading I get scoring values which I am not able to translate to a percentage.

The first version only contains Document with only a Name field and an ID field, which I am adding with the following code:

Document doc = new Document();
doc.Add(new Field("ID", studie.ID.ToString(), Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NO));
doc.Add(new Field("indexNaam", studie.Naam.Replace("-", " ").ToLower(), Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED, Field.TermVector.NO));

For searching I am using the following code:
      string strIndexDir = @"C:\deploys\deploy3\live\index_studies2";
      Analyzer std = new StandardAnalyzer(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_30);
      //TermQuery qry = new TermQuery(new Lucene.Net.Index.Term("indexNaam", trefwoord));
      Lucene.Net.QueryParsers.QueryParser parser = new Lucene.Net.QueryParsers.QueryParser(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_30, "indexNaam", std);
      Lucene.Net.Search.Query qry = parser.Parse(trefwoord);
      BooleanQuery bln = new BooleanQuery();

```
  Lucene.Net.Store.Directory directory = Lucene.Net.Store.FSDirectory.Open(new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(strIndexDir)); //Provide the directory where index is stored
  Lucene.Net.Search.Searcher srchr = new Lucene.Net.Search.IndexSearcher(Lucene.Net.Index.IndexReader.Open(directory, true));

  TopScoreDocCollector cllctr = TopScoreDocCollector.Create(100, true);
  bln.Add(qry,Occur.MUST);
  srchr.Search(bln, cllctr);

  ScoreDoc[] hits = cllctr.TopDocs().ScoreDocs;

  for (int i = 0; i < hits.Length; i++)
  {

    int docId = hits[i].Doc;
    float score = hits[i].Score;
    Lucene.Net.Documents.Document doc = srchr.Doc(docId);
    Studie studie =
      new Studie
      {
        ID = doc.Get("ID"),
        Naam = doc.Get("Naam"),
        ActualScore = score.ToString(),
        Score = System.Math.Round(score).ToString()
      };

   studies.Add(studie);

  }
```

I have also collected the scoring explanation and notice that the Inverse Document Frequency (idf) now determines the value of the Score property.
Is there a good way to retrieve the percentage scoring values and why was this changed?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3986220/how-do-i-normalise-a-solr-lucene-score