# Solr: Scores As Percentages

Tags: search, solr, lucene

First of all, I already saw [the lucene doc](https://wiki.apache.org/lucene-java/ScoresAsPercentages) which tells us to not produce score as percentages:

> People frequently want to compute a "Percentage" from Lucene scores to
>   determine what is a "100% perfect" match vs a "50%" match. This is
>   also somethings called a "normalized score"
>
> Don't do this.
>
> Seriously. Stop trying to think about your problem this way, it's not
>   going to end well.

Because of these recommandations, I used another way to solve my problem.

**However**, there are a few points of lucene's argumentation which I don't really understand why they are problematic in some cases.

For the case of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3986220/how-do-i-normalise-a-solr-lucene-score), I can easily understand why it is bad: if a user does a search and sees the following results:

- ProductA : 5 stars
- ProductB : 2 stars
- ProductC : 1 star

If ProductA was deleted after his first search, next time the user will come, he will be surprised if he sees the following results :

- ProductB : 5 stars
- ProductC : 3 stars

So, this problem **is exactly what Lucene's doc is pointing out**.

---

Now, let's take another example.

Imagine we have an e-commerce website which is using **'classic search'** combined with **phonetic search**. The phonetic search is here to avoid a maximum number of null results due to spelling mistakes. The score of phonetic results is very low relative to scores of classic search.

In this case, the first idea was to only return results which have **at least 10% of the maximum score**. Results under this threshold will not be considered as relevant for us, even with classic search.

If I do that, **I don't have the problem** of the above post because if a document is deleted, it seems logical if the old second product became the first one and the user will not be very suprised (it is the same behavior as if I kept the score as float value).

Furthermore, if scores of phonetic search are very low, as we expect, we will keep the same behavior to only return relevant scores.

---

So **my questions are**: is it always bad to normalize score as Lucene advises? Is my example an exception or is it a bad idea to do this even for my example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is, how do you determine your cutoff, and what does it mean?

Might be easier to look at an example.  Say I'm trying to look for people by last name.  I'm going to search for:

- "smithfield"

And I have the following documents that I think are all a pretty good match:

- smithfield - an exact match
- smithfielde - Pretty close, sound alike, only one (silent) letter off
- smythfield - Pretty close, sound alike, one vowel changed
- smithfelt - Couple letters off, but still close and sound alike
- snithfield - Not quite a soundalike, but only one letter off.  Maybe a typo.
- smittfield - Again, don't quite soundalike, maybe typo or misspelling
- smythfelt - Spelling a fair bit off, but could be a mishearing
- smithfieldings - Identical prefix

So, I've got four things I need to match.  Exact match should be ensured to have the highest score, and we want prefix, fuzzy and sound-alike matches.  So lets search for:

```
smithfield smithfield* smithfield~2 metaphone:sm0flt
```

**Results**

- smithfield ::: 2.3430576
- smithfielde ::: 0.97367656
- smythfield ::: 0.5657166
- smithfelt ::: 0.50767094

**< 10%** - Not displayed

- snithfield ::: 0.2137136
- smittfield ::: 0.2137136
- smythfelt ::: 0.0691447
- smithfieldings ::: 0.041700535

I thought smithfieldings was a pretty good match, but it's nowhere even close to making the cut!  It's less that *2%* of the maximum, nevermind 10%!  Okay, so let's try boosting

```
smithfield^4 smithfield*^2 smithfield~2 metaphone:sm0flt
```

**Results**

- smithfield ::: 2.8812196
- smithfielde ::: 0.5907072
- smythfield ::: 0.30413133

**< 10%** - Not displayed

- smithfelt ::: 0.2729258
- snithfield ::: 0.11489322
- smittfield ::: 0.11489322
- smithfieldings ::: 0.044836726
- smythfelt ::: 0.037172448

That's even worse!

And in production the problem  be worse still.  In the real world, you may be dealing with long complex queries, and full text documents.  Field length, repetitions of matches, coordination factors, boosts, and numerous query terms, all of it factors into the score.

It's really not all that unusual to see the first result be an order of magnitude higher in score than the second, even though the second is still a meaningful, interesting result.  There isn't any guarantee of an even distribution of scores, so we don't know what the 10% figure means.  And lucene's scoring algorithm tends to err on the side of making the differences nice and big.

---

Is it always bad?  I'd say yes.  As I see it, there are always two better options.

1 - Control your result set with good queries.  If you construct your query well, then *that* will provide the cutoff of your results, not because of some arbitrary cutoff in score, but because it won't be scored at all.

2 - If you don't want to do that, do you really gain anything by cutting off results at that arbitrary point?  Users are pretty good at recognizing when search results have gone off the deep end.  A user not being able to find what they want is a serious annoyance.  Showing too many results is usually a non-issue as long as they are ordered well.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and your explanation. I aggree and understand what you said in your section 2- about users but for things like facets, I think users could be lost.

Let's take an example, I am using phonetic with low boost. In french, we have the word `agenda` which means `diary`. When user is searching for `agenda`, phonetic gives results like `savon` which means `soap` because it contains the terms `agents nettoyants` (which means `cleaner`).

So, one of my first facet will be `soap` although my search is `diary` !? And even the smartest user will wonder what happens?!

Answer (score 5):

The Lucene score values are, as you've covered, only relevant for expressing the **relative strength each match within a *set* of matches**. Out of the context of a particular set of search results, the score for a particular record has **no absolute meaning**.

For this reason, the only appropriate normalization of the scores would be one to normalize the relationships between relevancy of documents within a result set, and even then you'll want to be very careful about how you employ this information.

Consider this result set, where we examine the score of each record as compared to the **immediately preceding result**:

```
ProductA         (Let's pretend the score is 10)
ProductB:  97%   (9.7)
ProductC:   8.5% (.82)
ProductD: 100%   (.82)
ProductE: 100%   (.82)
ProductF:  24%   (.2)
```

In this case, the first two results have very similar scores, while the next three have the same score but trail significantly. These numbers are clearly not to be shared with the shoppers online, but the low *relative* scores at ProductC and ProductF represent sharp enough drops that you *could* use them to inform other display options. Maybe ProductA and ProductB get displayed in a larger font than the others. If only one product appears before a precipitous drop, it could get even more special highlighting.

**I would caution against completely suppressing *relatively* lower scored results** in this kind of search. As you've already proven in your example, relative scores may be misleading, and unless your relevancy is very finely tuned the most relevant documents may not always be the most appropriate. It will do you no good if the desired results are dropped due to a single record that happens to repeat the search terms enough times to win a stellar score, and this is a real threat.

> For example, `"Hamilton Beach Three-In-One Convection Toaster Oven"` will match one in eight words against a search for `toaster`, while `"ToastMaster Toast Toaster Toasting Machine TOASTER"` will match as many as five in seven words depending on how you index. (Both product names are completely made up, but I wanted the second one to look less reputable.)

Also, **all returned documents *are matches***, no matter how low their scores might be. Sometimes a low-ranked result is the dark-horse find that the user really wants. Users will *not* understand that there are matching documents beyond what they see unless you tell them, so you might hide the trailing results on "page 2", or behind a cut, but you probably don't want to block them. Letting the user understand the size of their result set can also help them decide how to fine-tune their search. Using the significant drops in score as thresholds for paging could be very interesting, but probably a challenging implementation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Advices that you are given are good but ask a lot of work. To solve my example, I finally use a new requestHandler using phonetic only if "basic search" returns 0 result instead using a threshold.