# ElasticSearch - boosting the score of a particular field

Tags: java, elasticsearch, lucene

While applying boost value to a field, my score remains unaffected in elastic search and sometimes the score even gets reduced. Can anyone suggest something ?

```
MoreLikeThisQueryBuilder mltQuery2 =   QueryBuilders.moreLikeThisQuery("field1","field2")
        .ids(docId)
        .minTermFreq(1)                                 
        .maxQueryTerms(12);   

SearchResponse searchResponse =  client.prepareSearch(index).setTypes(indexType).setQuery(QueryBuilders.bolQuery()
        .should(mltQuery2.boost(50))
```

boost(50) does not increases the score.

Answer (score 0):

Applying a boost there doesn't really accomplish anything.  Boosts are used to enhance the impact of a subquery within the overall query.  So it would be something like this:

```
QueryBuilders.boolQuery
    .should(mltQuery.boost(50))
    .should(someOtherQueryBuilder);
```

There, your mlt query would be boosted to 50 times it's normal score *relative to the other subquery*.

The particular reason that changing the boost may even result in lower scores is because of the queryNorm scoring factor.  The overall score is multiplied by:

> 1 / ( q.getBoost()<sup>2</sup> · ∑ ( idf(t)  ·  t.getBoost() )<sup>2</sup> )<sup>1/2</sup>

This is designed to make the overall score of results sets be very roughly comparable.  For more, check out [Lucene's documentation of the scoring algorithm](https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_2_1/core/org/apache/lucene/search/similarities/TFIDFSimilarity.html), and [Elasticsearch provides an explanation as well.](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/practical-scoring-function.html#query-norm)

The thing to bear in mind is that scores are really only useful within the context of that particular query.  Attempting to save scores and/or compare them against the results of other queries is not a good idea (even with queryNorm around).  I get the impression you are trying to normalize scores.  Please see this question:

[how do I normalise a solr/lucene score?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3986220/how-do-i-normalise-a-solr-lucene-score/3998920#3998920)