# How to find if a document is a good match for a query, e.g., normalize elasticsearch score?

Tags: elasticsearch

The score computed by Elasticsearch provides a ranking between the documents, but it does not tell if the documents are a good match for the request. Currently, the first document can either match on all fields or just one. The only information that the score provides is that it is the best match.

Would it be possible to get a normalized score with respect to the query ? For example, a score of 1 would be a document matching perfectly the query and a score of 0.1 a document matching poorly.

Comment: Can anyone tell me why this question has been down voted ? I have read the content of [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/379271/3262646) and could not find why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, no, it is not possible to get a real normalized score for a query, but it is possible to get a good enough score normalization that works in many cases.

The problem to get a score that tells if the document is a good match or not for a query is to find what would be the best document for this query, and consequently the maximum score. Using elasticsearch and most (if not all) metrics, the maximum score is not bounded.

Even with a simple match query, you can technically reach an infinite score with a document that repeat the queried term an infinite number of time. Without bound on the score, it is not possible to get a true normalized score.

But all hopes are not lost. Instead of normalizing against the best possible score you can normalize against a fake ideal document which is supposed to get the maximum score. For example, if you are querying two fields `name` and `occupation` with queried terms `Jane Doe` and `Cook` your ideal document can be

```
{
    "name": "Jane Doe",
    "occupation": "Cook"
}
```

If the index contains a document with for example the name `Jane Jane Doe` then the ideal document may not get the maximum score. If the queried fields are relatively short, you probably do not have to worry about term duplication. If you have fields with many terms you may decide to duplicate some terms which are frequent in the ideal document. If the objective is to find if the document is a good match or not, it is usually not a problem to have a document scored higher than the ideal document.

The good news is that if you are using at least elasticsearch 6.4 you do not have to index the fake document to get its score for a query. You may use the endpoint [_scripts/painless/_execute](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/painless/6.4/painless-execute-api.html) to obtain the score of the ideal document.

```
GET _scripts/painless/_execute
{
    "script": {
        "source": "_score"
    },
    "context": "score",
    "context_setup": {
        "index": <INDEX>,
        "document": <THE_IDEAL_DOCUMENT>,
        "query": <YOUR_QUERY>
    }
}
```

Please note that the fields statistics of the fake document such as the number of documents containing a field and the number of fields containing the queried term will be taken into account when computing the score. If you have many documents, this should not be a problem, but for very not frequent field or term (say below 20) you can notice a lower score for the ideal document compared to a previously indexed document.

Comment: I am really interested in this case. How could it work with textual field/search? When I enter the same query in painless script I have a score of 0.78 and more than 200 in the standard query..

Comment: Using a script does not seems to work anymore. The field statistics are not taken into account when computing the score which is why you have different scores. I wrote [this article](https://medium.com/@pnmougel/relative-scoring-using-elasticsearch-479fda55c3b6) for other solutions. If you are interested in using the elasticsearch plugin for relative scoring, let me know the elasticsearch version you are using so I can update the plugin.

Comment: Thank you for the sharing. I've thought to use a similar thing with a parralel index and index the query as a doc here but I am afraid it messes with my statistics index and the delete on index doesn't seem efficient as you mention. Your plugin seems exactly what I want but I use ES 7.9.1. Let me know if I can help to maintain / update even if I'm a java noob :)

Comment: Hello, I have release a version of the plugin for es 7.9.1 :) However, maintaining the plugin compatibility is not very easy (it breaks even on minor version changes...). Sadly, I would not advise to use this plugin for a production app where elasticsearch is regularly updated unless you can spend some time to update it. If you are interested, I would be very happy with some help to maintain this project :)

Comment: Thank you so much for the new release. Ok I understand for the issue with fast moving environment for ES. I will try the plugin soon and let you know if it works for me. I am pretty sure it would help in lot of use case :)