# SOLR search filter by relevancy score

Tags: apache, search, solr, full-text-search, search-engine

So each SOLR search result has their own relevancy score:

https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrRelevancyFAQ

> "How can I see the relevancy scores for search results
>
> Request that the pseudo-field named "score" be returned by adding it
>   to the fl (field list) parameter. The "score" will then appear along
>   with the stored fields in returned documents. q=Justice
>   League&fl=*,score"

My question is...is it possible to filter SOLR results by this relevancy score?

Eg. perform a query in the nature of the following

```
Search for keyword "LOL" and only fetch documents whose relevancy score > 50
```

If it's possible how would you go about specifying this query syntactically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify a maximum number of results to return.  The results will appear in descending order by score, so you could stop processing at a specific point in the result set.

```
solr/search/select?q=LOL&&start=0&rows=10&fl=*%2Cscore
```

See the following article for a discussion about setting a minimum score: [Is it possible to set a Solr Score threshold 'reasonably', independent of results returned? (i.e. Is Solr Scoring standardized in any way)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8237714/is-it-possible-to-set-a-solr-score-threshold-reasonably-independent-of-result)

Answer (score 4):

I spent hours trying to filter out values with a relevance score of 0. I couldn't find any straight forward way to do this. I ended up accomplishing this with a workaround that assigns the query function to a local param. I call this local param in both the query ("q=") and the filter query ("fq=").

## Example

Let's say you have a query like:

```
q={!func}sum(*your arguments*)
```

First, make the function component its own parameter:

```
q={!func}$localParam
&localParam={!func}sum(*your arguments*)
```

Now to only return results with scores between 1 and 10 simply add a filter query on that localParam:

```
q={!func}$localParam
&localParam={!func}sum(*your arguments*)
&fq={!frange l=1 u=10 inclusive=true}$localParam
```

Answer (score 3):

solr 6.6:

add a solr filter query (`fq`):

```
q=SEARCH_PHRASE
&fq={!frange l=50.0}query($q,0)
```

in this case solr will return the result with "score" >= 50.0

`$q` in `query($q,0)` - it's like a reference to a `q` parameter

Comment: As you said """ $q in query($q,0) - it's like a reference to a q parameter """ does this means query function executes SEARCH_PHRASE again or it just takes the result of the main query. Does this method adds more load on solr ??

Comment: Excellent answer, learnt something new ++